# Storing a single csv object into an array

Tags: java, arrays, object, csv, io

hey ive got a chunk of code thats supposed loads lines of csv file into an array of objects:

```
public static WarehouseItem[] loadRecords(WarehouseItem[] records) {
  FileInputStream fileStrm = null;
  InputStreamReader rdr;
  BufferedReader bufRdr;
  int numRows = 0;
  String warehouseItem;
  String filename;

  filename = ConsoleInput.readLine("Please enter the filename (DataMillion.csv OR DataThousand.csv)");

  try {
    fileStrm = new FileInputStream(filename);
    rdr = new InputStreamReader(fileStrm);
    bufRdr = new BufferedReader(rdr);

    warehouseItem = bufRdr.readLine();
    records[numRows] = new WarehouseItem(warehouseItem);  //NULL POINTER EXCEPTION HERE
    System.out.println(records[0].toString(records[0].columnVals));
    while (warehouseItem != null) {
      numRows++;
      records[numRows] = new WarehouseItem(warehouseItem);
      warehouseItem = bufRdr.readLine();
    }
  fileStrm.close();
  }

  catch (IOException e) {
    if (fileStrm != null) {
      try { 
    fileStrm.close(); 
      } catch (IOException ex2) {}
    }
    System.out.println("Error in file processing: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    main(null);
    return records;
}
```

but when i run it, i get a NullPointerException on the line

`records[numRows] = new WarehouseItem(warehouseItem);`

is there anything that i missed??

heres the WarehouseItem constructor + toString:

```
public class WarehouseItem {
  String[] columnVals;
  int numColumns = 5;

public WarehouseItem(String warehouseItem) {
  String key, brand, model, price, weightInKG;
  int intWeightInKG;
  double doublePrice; 
  StringTokenizer strTok;

  strTok = new StringTokenizer(warehouseItem, ",");
    key = strTok.nextToken();
    brand = strTok.nextToken();
    model = strTok.nextToken();
    intWeightInKG = Integer.parseInt(strTok.nextToken());
    doublePrice = Double.valueOf(strTok.nextToken());

    weightInKG = String.valueOf(intWeightInKG);
    price = String.valueOf(doublePrice);
  String[] columnVals = {key, brand, model, weightInKG, price};

  if(columnVals.length != 5)
    throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid CSV: not enough columns");
}

public String toString(String[] columnVals) {
  return ("Key:     " + columnVals[0] + "\n" + 
      "Brand:   " + columnVals[1] + "\n" + 
      "Model:   " + columnVals[2] + "\n" + 
      "Weight:  " + columnVals[3] + "\n" + " kg" + 
      "Price:   " + "$" + columnVals[4] + "\n");
}
}
```

What my problem is the values aren't getting stored into the array records properly and im not sure why

Comment: how do i initialize it so that the max number of records is 1000000(1million)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an array of objects in Java, it is initialized with all nulls. That is why you get a nullpointerexception.

So you need to create an object for each array position. In fact instead of calling a method you could just make that method a constructor; that would be simpler.

I also noticed another mistake: the method sets local variables, which only exist for the lifetime of the method, when in fact it should set instance variables.

Then I noticed a third mistake: You just caught exception, and assumed that that indicated missing columns; in fact it could indicate invalidly-typed data inside a column (e.g. string instead of integer).

Comment: hey thank you for the feedback but what do you mean make the method a constructor? sorry im fairly new

Comment: Do you know what a constructor is?

Comment: yeah just a little familiar with it

Comment: I mean you could change `processLine` into the constructor for the `WarehouseItem` class.

Comment: `records[numRows] = new WarehousItem(warehouseItem)` instead of `records[numRows].processLine(warehouseItem)`.

Comment: yes thank you i just figured that out ive just got to check the exception problem you stated now because im getting that error

Comment: How many objects OP should create 1000000? Wouldn't it heap impact?

Comment: This is creating objects dynamically so it only creates as many objects as necessary.

Comment: you said "create an object for each array position". How many positions available in the array?

Comment: Sorry, yes, that's true. But the solution in my comment above does not create an object for each array position.

Comment: Anyway unnecessary space is occupied by the array. And what assumptions have been made to create such capacity? Why this capacity is hardcoded into the array?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't initialize array, that was a cause `NullPointerException` in your code, but if you can't use array don't use it.

The number of lines might exceed the capacity of array, use `List` instead

```
List<WarehouseItem> records = new ArrayList<>();

String line = bufRdr.readLine();
while (line != null) {
  WarehauseItem warehauseItem = new WarehauseItem();
  records.add(warehauseItem);
  warehauseItem.processLine(line);
  line = bufRdr.readLine();
}
numRows = records.size();
```

Comment: Nope, he's just not creating the individual `WarehouseItem`s.

Comment: @Kevin How is not creating if the `processLine` is called?

Comment: Trying to call `processLine` is the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @nikpon Not in yours, the original OP's complaint was the NPE caused by him not initializing the array elements.

Comment: Yes, it just looks to me like you're implying the error was caused by too many lines. Edit to make it clear the original error was caused by not initializing, and this is just a better approach, then I'll retract my dv.

Comment: Please explain to Jad Sapida about IndexOutOfBoundsException and NullPointerException when it will occurs in his program. He is not asked about you to change entire code.

Comment: @ByteCode Jad Sapida doesn't respond, and reads all comments out there and I changed only part caused the NPE in his/her code, and told him/her to use correct code.

Comment: Much better. Reversed.

Answer (score 1):

You missed object creation  `records[numRows]=new WarehouseItem();`

Your code need to be like this.

```
while (warehouseItem != null) {
      records[numRows]=new WarehouseItem();  //here you forgot the object creation.
      warehouseItem = bufRdr.readLine();
      records[numRows].processLine(warehouseItem);
      numRows++; 
 }
```

Comment: This will produce `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @nikpon yes if the line count is above 1000000 then it will throw IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: So, your code is unpredictable behavior, you even didn't catch it.

Comment: OP catches only IOException, and doesn't care about indexes when using array nor capacity occupied.

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't assigned anything to records[numRows]. You only defined records as an array of WarehouseItem objects.
You should assign a new WarehouseItem to that index of the array before you can use.

```
records[numRows] = new WarehouseItem();
warehouseItem = bufRdr.readLine();
records[numRows].processLine(wareHouseitem);
```

Comment: This will produce `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.